# EMV Payment using nfc

Tags: android, nfc, payment, emv

I was wondering if it is possible to use the NFC in smartphones with android as a POS terminal not as wallet. The idea is to pay with EMV cards, instead of using an external reader or a validator. Something like [this](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/emv). Perhaps, implementing the required protocol it could transfer data, but I'm not sure. In case that was possible if I want my application to be PCI certified should I certified the phone as well?

#### Context:

Perhaps an example of how it would be used may clarify which is the purpose of this.

Let's say that you are going to take a train and you have to pay someone for the ticket. So, this person puts your emv card into his phone and makes a transaction, that info is obtained through the nfc in his phone and sent to a payment gateway, so you get an email with the info of the transaction.

Any idea of how or where to start would be appreciate it. Thanks :D

Comment: Generally no. Unless the issuer has provided an app that would handle issuer-specific NFC encryption. Otherwise it would be possible to steal NFC information from an unaware card owner.

Comment: What more could you take out ( "steal" ) from a card using a mobile phone nfc reader which is not possible with a conventional POS terminal ? and what is the role of issuer app when the question is about acquiring ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the software for android is possible, but like Adarsh mentioned, your limitation with a regular phone is that it's not going to be able to emit the magnetic field to power on the chip in a credit card.  There are handful of android devices that have the contactless readers built in, as well as contact readers (chip insert).  See Pax and Castle Technologies, for example.  They're like an android phone, but a bit bulkier to accommodate the readers.  (Not sure if you can make phone calls on them though, so it might not really be a phone.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very much possible. I have refered [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc) and made a reader on on my own in the past. But I guess it has some dependancy with the hardware also. As a wallet you get  waves from a reader(transponder) whereas when acting as a reader you should have a transponder hardware on the mobile device. I suggest you to read on this part more before you take this up. ( eg. iphone do not have nfc transponder to my knowledge ).

For a positive case of the above scenario, you should receive ATR from card, which marks the start of your reader's conversation with the card. Now follows SELECT, GET PO, READ, GEN AC combined with terminal risk management, cardholder verification, online request to your acquirer and receiving the response from acquirer to understand the fate of your authorization.

You will need to certify with each payment scheme before accepting their cards.
Android Studio has made it so simple that this was my second Android project after hello world and I completed in a month for a DPAS card.